# get url links from bs4.BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to get only `href` which start with `https`.

```
 (some texts(type='bs4.BeautifulSoup')).find_all("a",href="https") can not get url links.
```

I am making crawling tools.

Comment: did you try `[i['href'] for i in find_all('a')]` ?

Comment: list=[] for elem in soup.select("a"):
             list.append(elem.get("href"))                                                              but it includes like  '/app/home/p/10537' not only like  'https://news.yahoo.co.jp/fc'

Answer (score 0):

Use css attribute = value selector with starts with ^ operator. Pretty sure a dupe but can't quickly find a good example.

```
 links = [link['href'] for link in soup.select('[href^='https'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also filter the `href` attribute of the a tag using a regular expression in *find_all*

```
soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('^https'))
```

Demo

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html="""
<a href="https://www.google.com">Secure</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Not Secure</a>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('^https')))
```

Outputs:

```
[<a href="https://www.google.com">Secure</a>]
```

Documentation:

[The keyword arguments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

[A regular expression as filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression)